# What are the security benefits (or drawbacks) to wrapping a HTTP server around a SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, http, security

Assume the server is public, and only requires a password to interface with.

The public option seems to be "always restrict your SQL Server to known IP's".

When I respond with "What if I want anyone to be able to connect to the server?" I am told I should basically set up a HTTP server to act as a mediator between the SQL Server and the public.

Wouldn't it just open up my server to now not only attacks on SQL but also HTTP? Wouldn't keeping the system as simple as possible be the right move from a security standpoint?

What type of attack(s) in particular would this protect against?

Comment: As simple as possible but no simpler. *Simple* means at least creating a VPN between clients and server. `the sever is public, and only requires a password to interface with.` that's not simple, that's breached. And indefensible should anything happen

Comment: It wouldn't protect you from any kind of attacks. The exact opposite in fact, it would open you up to new types of attacks. You don't want to make your sql server available like this at all.

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean by “like this”? Are you referring to wrapping it or not wrapping it in HTTP?

Comment: By "like this" he means making it open on the global internet.

Comment: @SeanLange This is what makes since to me!! But everyone is telling me to wrap it in HTTP because this will somehow protect it from an attack no one can seem to name

Comment: Again wrapping a server is not something that makes sense. Not from a security standpoint, but there is no such thing as wrapping a server with a server. Just like there is no such thing as a unicorn. Nobody here has told you to expose your sql server via HTTP. It will NOT protect anything, it is exposing it. Perhaps you can share what "everyone" is telling you. The context could be HUGE in your situation.

Comment: I have a desktop application which talks to a SQL server. I need anyone to be able to access the SQL server regardless of where they are connected. People are advising I set up an HTTP server to interface with the SQL server instead of making my SQL sever open to anyone with a password

Comment: Based on the responses to this, I posted a spin off question which is more direct here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58920896/10577103

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; If you make an SQL server open to the public there is high chance you will be hacked in short order.

SQL servers are not designed to be open to the public and no one does so.  Unlike web servers which are designed to be open and have been hammered at a lot.   You also don't want to be giving everyone a password to your SQL server.  To have a secure data layer you want to have just one account (often called a service account) connecting and have a limited set of functions it can do (eg only read data for most tables, only write to specific tables).  The more you can restrict who can access your database the better.  Many designs will include firewalls around to DB server to ensure that only specific machines are accessing it.  Kerberos allows you to restrict what applications on specific machine access it.  In fact, this is often done to secure sensitive applications.

Web sites and applications on the other hand are designed to handle a lot of different users and stay secure.  There are standard designs (eg hashed and salted passwords) that are built into libraries.  It is "easy" to secure HTTP because everyone does and it is well understood.

Don't open your SQL server to the public.  Everyone is giving you good advice.

If it was not clear from the above (and based on your edit) the following is true

**Not making your SQL server open to the public protects from EVERY type of hacking attack**

Comment: Can you give an example of an attack it would protect against? I believe you are correct, I am just trying to better understand

Comment: @tyler give me an example of an attack you think it won't protect against.

Comment: I can’t, but I also can’t name any attacks I am currently vulnerable too. So therefor do not understand in a concrete since what I am achieving by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few considerations here.

Firstly, databases are among the crown jewels for attackers - they contain a lot of juicy information - credit card details, personal information, passwords are all stored in databases. So, attackers who see a publicly available database server (of whatever flavour) will put a lot of energy into attacking it.

Secondly, once your database is compromised, attackers can do *anything* they want - drop the database, truncate tables if they are vandals, or create triggers which automatically email them with new information if they're trying to steal data.

Thirdly, most database protocols are not encrypted by default - the data passes across the wire in plaintext (unlike, for instance, HTTPS). This often includes authentication information. So, an attacker who can sniff traffic between your database and a legitimate user can steal all sorts of data, often including username/password. It's possible to encrypt the connection, but it's not done by default.

When people say "wrap it in HTTP", what they mean is create a domain-specific API, using proven authentication and authorization mechanisms which can withstand all the internet throws at them. Limit what users of your data can do via an API, so you don't accidentally allow someone to write a SQL query which consumes all the memory on your machine.

Comment: All major databases allow for TLS connections, most architectures don't include that as a requirement (but they should.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most important point here is what kind of Application you are building and what Database you are using.

I have experience developing a desktop application for Windows that has an MSSQL server in the cloud that is open to the public internet with password/login tls sql connections for replication and queries and even with your http server this is the maximum security you are gonna get. 
Using Role Based Access Control it is secured. I have never heard of any data leaks from that company. It is the biggest company in the country in its field with thousands of users.
But this is still not HIPPA compliant so after 10 years of using this architecture the company is rewriting the app from scratch using a REST API to go out on the EU and US markets.

Some Databases like CouchDB or Elastic Search provide http endpoints out of the box, and Role Based Access Control options to secure those endpoints with login/password schemes. This is HIPPA compliant.

So if you are willing to go the server-less route you should first of all choose your database wisely.